# Loop checkbox from database values PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Working on something and having problems with some code. The scenario is that an item should have multiple categories. my solution is to loop create checkboxes so that the user may simply click on the categories the item should have this is the code i have.

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_category order by name ");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    echo '<label>'.$row['name']. '</labe>' 
    '<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value='.$row['category_id'].' >';

?>
```

Somehow it's not working would appreciate any help on this.

Also if someone could give me idea on how to store the values like **ITEM APPLE** has *values* of A,G,Y how would i store it in the database and how should show it. because i will be using **SELECT ELEMENT** filters to search them.

EDIT: error prompt

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\nota\add2.php on line 25

Comment: You're missing an 'l' in your label end tag. 
All this must be inside a form.

Comment: Thanks, Didn't notice. Still trying to find how to fix this.

Comment: Fix the error in your code first. You cant combine two quoted strings without a concat (.) between them.

Comment: `echo '<label>'.$row['name']. '</label>'.'<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value='.$row['category_id'].'>';`
Your echo should look like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 echo '<label>'.$row['name']. '</labe>'.'<input type="checkbox" name="categories" value='.$row['category_id'].' >';
```

you are missing an string concatenation operator `.` in  echo    statement .i suppose that your query is correct and there is some data in your database.

And about storing `ITEM APPLE has values of A,G,Y` 
you can use a look up table which has the `id` of `ITEM APPLE`  and values as A then same id but value as G and then y..etc a

this schema is best suited if an item can have multiple value .

[link to database schema](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/72cb7b/2)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm thinking of using an IfElse to check for boxes that are selected and will store in the db. but on the searching would a `select *  . ..  where value=A, Or G OR Y` or should i remove the "," from the db first then use the select statement?

Comment: if you use a comma then your above select * ... will not work